# How to solve the wrong variable type error when handling imbalance dataset by ROSE in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, imbalanced-data

I am learning R with the [Fraud Transaction data](https://www.kaggle.com/ealaxi/paysim1). When I try to use ROSE to handle the imbalanced dataset, the `only handle continuous and categorical variables` error pops up.

Here's what I tried:

```
str(dataset)
'data.frame':   6362620 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ step            : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ type            : chr  "PAYMENT" "PAYMENT" "TRANSFER" "CASH_OUT" ...
 $ amount          : num  9840 1864 181 181 11668 ...
 $ nameOrig        : chr  "C1231006815" "C1666544295" "C1305486145" "C840083671" ...
 $ oldbalanceOrg   : num  170136 21249 181 181 41554 ...
 $ newbalanceOrig  : num  160296 19385 0 0 29886 ...
 $ nameDest        : chr  "M1979787155" "M2044282225" "C553264065" "C38997010" ...
 $ oldbalanceDest  : num  0 0 0 21182 0 ...
 $ newbalanceDest  : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ isFraud         : int  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ isFlaggedFraud  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ balancedOfOrigin: num  -9840 -1864 -181 -181 -11668 ...
 $ balancedOfDest  : num  0 0 0 21182 0 ...

datadata_ROSE <- ROSE(isFraud~., data = dataset, N = 500, seed = 111)$data
```

With Error:

> Error in rose.sampl(n, N, p, ind.majo, majoY, ind.mino,
> minoY, y, classy,  :    The current implementation of ROSE handles
> only continuous and categorical variables.

Debugging:

```
# change the isFraud attribute into category 0/1
dataset$isFraud = as.factor(dataset$isFraud)
datadata_ROSE <- ROSE(isFraud~., data = dataset, N = 500, seed = 111)$data
```

At the end, the error still cannot be solved. How can I turn the dataset fit ROSE model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your `str` part, `type`, `nameOrig`, `nameDest` are still character not factor. It will work with change them to factors. But when I look at `nameOrig` and `nameDest`, it's not seems to be appropriate to included in `ROSE`.

```
dummy2 <- head(dataset, 100)

dummy2$isFraud = as.factor(dummy2$isFraud)

#additional part.
dummy2 <- dummy2 %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type),
         nameDest = factor(nameDest),
         nameOrig = factor(nameOrig))
dummy3 <- ROSE(isFraud~., data = dummy2, N = 500, seed = 111)$data
```

Comment: Thanks for your brief explanation!! One more question, I see lots of function has the parameter `seed`. From the doc., it tells its to keep trace of the generated sample. I guess its controlling the randomness of generating data? Usually how large or small should I set it?

Comment: @WILLIAM `seed` is to fix randomness while fitting `ROSE`. You may get constant result and also reproducible to others. It's recommendable to fix it as what you want. Large or small doesn't matter. Since you use `seed` as `111`, it's ok to just keep that `111` while fitting that model.